# C LANGUAGE >NOOB HERE< what did i do wrong?

Tags: c

```
 for(a=0;a<99;a++){
        reg:
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\t~~REGISTER AN ACCOUNT~~\n\n");
        printf("\tDesired Username: ");
        scanf("%s", &user[a].user);
        for(b=0;b<=a-1;b++){
            if(strcmp(user[a].user,user[b].user)==0){
                printf("USERNAME IS ALREADY TAKEN");
                system("pause");
                goto reg;
            }
        }
        printf("\tDesired Password: ");
        scanf("%s", &user[a].pass);
        printf("\tPersonal/Company Name: ");
        scanf("%s", &user[a].name);
        printf("\tAddress/Location: ");
        scanf("%s", &user[a].address);
        printf("\tEmail-Address: ");
        scanf("%s", &user[a].email);
        printf("\tContact Number: 09");
        scanf("%d", &user[a].contact);
        break;
    }
```

whenever I put the `break` in the end the system doesn't recognise if the username is taken or not, but when 'break' is removed it can recognise it.. idk how is this happening.. please help..

PS. sorry if this looks or sounds really stupid to you I am just starting to learn to program(I m trying to make a register program with a very limited knowledge for a school project)

Comment: Use `continue` rather than `goto reg;`. Will not fix the issue but is much better style. **But see the next comment as a blind change will introduce a bug.**

Comment: @Bathsheba - Not that I condone `goto` being used here, but a `continue` won't have the same semantics (`a` will be incremented).

Comment: Add more of your program. Are you correctly allocating memory?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Oops. Yet another refactoring bug introduced...

Comment: The `break` statement renders the outer `for` useless. It forces exiting the outer `for` loop after it is executed only once.

Comment: @Bathsheba - The bugs go deeper. I missed the inner `for` myself.

Comment: Goto considered harmful! Actually, all the arguments against using `goto` also apply to `continue`. Except `goto` can actually be used in non-harmful ways. `continue` can only be used for non-conditional branches upwards. This is why MISRA-C:2012 allows `goto` but bans `continue`.

Comment: Please consider the fact that `%s` scans a whitespace-terminated string, which is not suitable for many of those fields. It's not the best way to read user input, consider using `fgets()` read full lines and then parsing those. Much more robust.

Comment: (And the correct solution is to use neither goto nor continue, but a `return`. This gives the most readable code and also puts clean-up code in a central place. Basially `void func (void) { stuff=allocate(); algorithm(stuff); free(stuff); }`.)

Comment: @Lundin: Which only adds weight to the argument that I am borderline unemployable.

Comment: Interestingly this is not said please post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please use a title that states your problem (except your problem is you are new to c which is something we can't fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your for loops:

**First iteration:**

`a = 0;`

```
for(b=0;b<=a-1;b++)
```

will not be true

as `b<=a-1` equates to `b<=-1` which is not true. Hence it will not enter the for loop for b. It will go to break and exit

Same process will repeat until `a>=2`,

When you don't have break , b waits for `b>=2` and starts comparing. That's why you see result of comparison.

A simple check would be to print out values of a and b at every iteration.

Comment: Please format your code. I haven't checked if your answer is correct, but still you should consider that `goto`, `break` and `continue` should be avoided in most cases.